# "In the race she came second" or "In the race she came in second". Which is right?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

Which is the  right sentence between the two?

> 1. In the race, she **came** second.
> 2. In the race, she **came in** second.

Answer (score 5):

Your first sentence

> In the race, she came second.

is correct meaning there was one person ahead of her.

Your second sentence is a shortened form of

> In the race, she came *in* second *(place)*.

It would be incorrect to say

> In the race, she came second *place*.

In general usage, your two sentences are basically equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Both are equally correct. You'd probably say the first when talking about different people's positions:

> In the race, she came second after Jane who came first.

You may say the second when describing her relative performance to other times she ran the race:

> In the race, she came in second, while last year she came in third.

But the two are *so* close, that the distinction is probably my own interpretation.

Comment: +1 I particularly like  your disclaimer, which is a point that should be hammered on!

Answer (score 1):

Both the examples are fine, in speech nobody would blink an eye, but perhaps the second one (*groan*) is the least convincing, stylistically, because the preposition **in** is repeated twice.

A short and sweet alternative could be:

> She came second (place) **in** the race

The OP needn't worry about using the expression "second place in the race", it is perfectly acceptable.

Examples taken from [Google News](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22second+place+in+the+race%22&tbm=nws) (July - October 2016)

- The fight of Hamilton for ***second place in the race*** with Max Verstappen has been what has put the spice in the final laps and the younger racer ...
- *The car ***was in second place in the race*** *when Walsh pitted on lap 54 after a strong stint, in which he had traded fastest times with the leading Red Bull ...*
- *Casey White* ***took second place in the race*** *in 16:27, while Austin Hallabrin finished third in 16:49, Nick Weiss was fourth in 16:56
- ***Second place in the race*** *for the Austrians and fourth for the Danes leaves the teams tied on points – but it's advantage Red Bull Sailing Team ...*
- *But I* ***got second place in the race***, *and the No. 1 guy ran a (15:13), so I obviously wasn't keeping up with him, but I still wanted to run faster*
- *Ultimately, Leonard* ***took second place in the race***. *At the final finish line, event organizers produced a matching medal for Gobi, too*.
- *Canadian yachtsman Lawrence Lemieux […]. The International Olympic committee awarded his bravery for plucking a fellow competitor from the sea during a race. He was also* ***awarded second place in the race*** despite finishing 21st.
- *Donald Trump has* ***fallen  to second place in the race*** *for the Republican presidential nomination, according to a new poll.*

So you can use other verbs than *come* for races, such as: *take*, *be*, *get*, *be awarded*, and even *fall*.

Oxford Dictionaries has an entry which explains

> **[place](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/place)**
>   3.1 *British*
>   Any of the first three or sometimes four positions **in a race** (used especially of the second, third, or fourth positions).

Comment: *She came in second in the race* or *In the race she came in second* or *She came in in second place* are all idiomatic; this thing about avoiding repetition of prepositions is specious. Ain't no such thang.  It happens all the time in conversation, and prosodic cues provide plenty of disambiguation. *She came second place* would be unidiomatic.

Comment: @TRomano They're both fine, **in speech** nobody would blink an eye... but the preposition *in* is repeated twice...all things true. And the (place) was there to show what "second" meant, just in case somebody didn't know. Lastly, "To come second place **in** a race" IS idiomatic.

Comment: "She came first place in the race" is not idiomatic. You can *come second* in a race, but you don't *come second place* in a race.

Comment: You had my downvote for three reasons. 1) Introducing a prohibition, grammatical or stylistic, which runs counter to actual idiomatic usage. *She came **in in** second place* is perfectly fine. Phrasal contours ({came in} {in second place} ) prevent an "in in" collision. 2) Claiming that "*came* second place" is viable. And then 3) insisting that it is viable, in  your comment.

Comment: @TRomano where did you say that *come* cannot be used in:  but you don't "... *come second place* in a race." If you can *take*, *get*, *fall*, and *be* in second place in a race, I don't see the big deal with *"come"*. Only the words "*come second place*" were italicized in your comments. The expression you took objection with was "second place in the race", which  is perfectly acceptable, and you know it.

Comment: In my first comment and then in my second comment.

Answer (score 0):

Both are equally correct.  If you said one to a native speaker, not only would he instantly know your meaning, but a minute later, he would not remember which usage you chose.

*However*, I'd like to make a minor point.  Consider the following sentences:

- She came second.
- She came in second.

The first sentence just means she came second is some sequence: a race, a line of people through a door, the priorities given by her husband (eek!)

The second sentence can only refer to a race.  When you "come in" first or second or third, it's in a race or competition of some sort.

It's my advice to use the more specific word or phrase whenever you can.